# Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. When sudo apt update with WSL 2

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

```
$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

- System: Windows 10 PRO 19044.1415
- WSL 2, Ubuntu 20.04

`ping` to google.com also fails: `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

---

**Already done:**

- `wsl.conf` with those lines inside of it:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

- re-created `resolv.conf` with several `nameserver`'s:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

---

**Tried:**

- to add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` into `wsl.conf`. Doesn't work.
- keep single `nameserver` line inside of `resolv.conf`
- followed [those steps](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5256#issuecomment-666545999)
- `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow` from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4585#issuecomment-610061194)

---

Question replaced from StackOverflow

Comment: are you able to ping ip adresses, e.g. `ping -c 2 1.1.1.1` ?

Comment: @mashuptwice nope. It returns `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Obviously configuring a DNS server won't work if there is no network connectivity at all. 
You may check if there is a ip assigned to your WSL instance.

Comment: So, how i should do it? There is no `ifconfig` command.

Comment: `ipconfig` on your windows host, `ip a` on your WSL. It may help if you read some articles about WSL or watch a youtube video to get an idea of the basics

Comment: So. `ipconfig` from `cmd` shows there are `Adapter Ethernet vEthernet (WSL)`.

Comment: It may help to read some articles or watch youtube videos about WSL to get to know what the commands do, what the output means and **which part of the output** is relevant to your specific issue.

Comment: Try restarting [LxssManager](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5611) after you have modified `wsl.conf`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777927/apt-get-update-failed-on-wsl2) suggests it's a proxy or firewall issue.

Comment: @Ramhound tried to restart LxssManager. Not helped. About proxy or firewall: i'm not using proxy and tried to add wsl to firewall exceptions, this also doesn't worked.

Comment: Research reasons WSL2 not having internet, or are you unable to ping, Google on Windows also?

Comment: Only WSL2. Ping on Windows machine is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found asnwer. It isn't even my fault...

[This advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340554/10872199) helped me, and `sudo apt update` finally worked. If u dont' have `.wslconfig` file, create it yourself.

Ended up with this inside of `resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 208.67.222.222  # OpenDNS address
nameserver 192.168.0.10  # ipv4 address of your windows machine. *1
```

*1 - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67429140/10872199)

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be relevant in my case:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#no-internet-access-in-wsl

I had to shutdown Symantec Network Threat Protection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Type the command below and run it. Then update again.**

```
wget --no-check-certificate http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring_2022.1_all.deb
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please elaborate some more on how your answer is better than the one posted by the OP himself, as well as provide some background information on what your command does and why. Otherwise this answer is likely to be deleted.